# How to play RTSP[live streaming] link in android?

Tags: live, rtsp, live-streaming, android-videoview

I am trying to play RTSP live streaming url "rtsp://164.100.51.207/broadcast/DDLive".
But i am getting this error (1,-1).

I am trying this code

```
VideoView myVideoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoPlayer);
         myVideoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(url.toString()));        
        myVideoView.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));
         myVideoView.requestFocus();  
        myVideoView.start();
```

this code giving error(1,-1).
I am unable to play this link.If anyone tell me idea to play this url.

thinks.

Comment: where have you set the rtsp link in your code ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Roundabout suggestion -

1. download the rtsp stream to a local filesink using VLC which has just been compiled on android.
2. once the download is complete, simply play that file using the normal Intent field values for  a local file and mimetype of mp4.

snip below should play what was downloaded.

```
new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW).setDataAndType(Uri.parse("file:///mnt/sdcard/myfile.mp4"), "video/mp4");
```

VLC on android links:
http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1517415
http://code.google.com/p/android-vlc-remote/source/browse/AndroidManifest.xml

**Get an rtsp link from any youtube vide - slightly involved process**

You can stream just about any youtube video as RTSP if you do the following:

1. Get the youtube video ID - like *videoID=kgfctMNeDtg*
2. Get the youtube feed for the videoID
3. Find the rtsp url for the appropriate *youtube format* . Formats 1,5 6 all have rtsp
4. request the rtsp uri with an instance of HttpClient

Details:

http://snipplr.com/view/63341/youtube-rtsp-cli-request--audio-track-only-p2/

http://snipplr.com/view/57846/curl--rtsp-to-get-sdp-descriptor-for-media-stream/

Answer (score 2):

I tried playing rtsp://164.100.51.207/broadcast/DDLive on VLC but was unsuccessful in doing so, here is the error I get

[image]

Try another link that works like rtsp://217.146.95.166:554/playlist/ch12zqcif.3gp (Some indian channel)

Comment: ya.. I am trying other RTSP file that are working fine.but, this url i am not able to play.tell me any suggestion about this url. This url not possible to play android phone ha???? try this one rtmp://flashmedia.nic.in:80/live/dd1

Comment: Yup, I think the server is down for this stream so you cannot access it from any device, mobile or otherwise. That stream is not working either